# Get RTSP stream from ip camera (ffmpeg)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtsp

I wrote in cmd:

```
ffmpeg -y -re -acodec pcm_s16le -rtsp_transport tcp -i
rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/11 -vcodec copy -af asetrate=22050 -acodec
aac -b:a 96k test.mp4
```

and I got a video file. If I write this command in python:

```
import os  
os.system("ffmpeg -y -re -acodec pcm_s16le -rtsp_transport tcp -i 
rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/11 -vcodec copy -af asetrate=22050 -acodec aac -b:a 96k test.mp4")
```

I get this error:

> "ffmpeg" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥� ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ���
>   ������ 䠩���.

I tried to create a bat file and run it from python, but I get the same error. If I don't run it in python, all is good.

How do I start recording a video stream from an ip camera in python?

Comment: Syntax highlighting already shows where you have incorrect syntax.

Comment: the error lies with your use of quotes. Correct the misplaced quotes and your program should run

Comment: `os.system('ffmpeg -y -re -acodec pcm_s16le -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.200:554/11 -vcodec copy -af asetrate=22050 -acodec aac -b:a 96k test.mp4')`

does not work